# How to remove laravel php framework

Tags: laravel, ubuntu-14.04

I installed *Laravel PHP framework* in ubuntu 14.04. But I want to uninstall it. I'm not getting any help about this.
Check the screen shot:
[image: laravel]
It says, "I've arrived", but I don't find any related laravel file in my system.
Please help me.

Comment: I'm not getting that file in my lamp files and localhost redirects me to laravel always

Comment: Actually, its really just the folder. Maybe also clear your browser cache and restart apache

Answer (score 5):

A Laravel installation is just a folder containing source code. Remove it and you're all set.

If you created a MySQL database or something similar, you may want to delete that as well.

Comment: I'm not getting that file in my lamp files and localhost redirects me to laravel always.  And there is no DB for laravel.

Comment: You'll need to check your LAMP config and see where it's pointing. **Somewhere** on your system you have a Laravel install.

Comment: That is brilliant idea :)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to disable laravel.conf then go to terminal and paste below line

```
sudo a2ensite 000-default.conf
```

check if exist conf file by cd /etc/apache2/sites-available

and if you want to enable laravel again then

```
sudo a2dissite laravel.conf
```

> for more check link
>   https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/install-laravel-on-ubuntu-for-apache/

Comment: Your solution worked for me after 5 Hours of head bang...thankyou

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo a2dissite laravel.conf
a2dismod rewrite
sudo systemctl restart apache2.service
```

Comment: Can you explain that further? How does this "uninstall" or "remove" anything?

Comment: If you have given servername as localhost in config file then it always shows laravel page when open localhost.
By running those commands i can see apache page.
That worked for me

Comment: ...but it does not uninstall anything. It just removes the mapping between an apache host and the directory. Additionally, this is already part of another answer, so you should highlight why yours is different and maybe better